# Gitkraken striketrough branch name

Tags: git, gitkraken

I am using Gitkraken, some branches name started to shown like as in the image (striketrough). It was first for one branch, it increases to three branch somehow and I don't know why and how to resolve the issue.  I fear, other branches might will be effected.

[image: gitkraken strikethrough branch name]

Comment: Seeing the same thing on mine, usually accompanied by a mystery commit not connected to the rest of the graph.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is just a visual bug that occurs at times when there are many branches in the repository.  According to one of their support representatives:
[image]
[image]